# Is async keyword necessary in the method signature when calling another async method internally?

Tags: c#, asynchronous

Here's a C# async code snippet. Is GetAsync the same as GetAsync2? Is GetAsync a right implementation?

```
    public Task<IHttpActionResult> GetAsync()
    {
        return GetOneAsync();
    }
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetAsync2()
    {
        return await GetOneAsync();
    }
    private async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetOneAsync()
    {
        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            await httpClient.GetAsync("http://baidu.com");
        }
        return Ok();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not the same. `GetAsync` does not generate a state machine and does not wait for the result of `GetOneAsync`, which is the preferred option when the result of the `async` method is not needed in this method.

The resulting code is more efficient as well as no state machine is generated and no context switch is required.

See [Understanding the cost of Async/Await](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh456402.aspx) article for more info.

Comment: Worth mentioning: while it is more efficient, it has subtly different semantics if `GetOneAsync` throws synchronously. (Which this version of `GetOneAsync` won't do.)

Comment: @hvd By different semantics, do you mean to say that the exception won't be thrown until it is observed?

Comment: Yes. Given `private Task<IHttpActionResult> GetOneAsync() { throw new NotImplementedException(); }` (note the lack of `async`), your `GetAsync()` throws immediately, whereas your `GetAsync2()` wraps `GetOneAsync()`'s exception in a `Task<IHttpActionResult>`.

Comment: @hvd in your code, what implementation do you prefer?

Comment: @Bargitta I prefer giving synchronous exceptions whenever possible and reasonable (the "fail fast" principle), and I would even write `public Task FooAsync(object o) { if (o == null) throw ArgumentNullException("o"); return FooAsyncImpl(o); } private async Task FooAsyncImpl(object o) { ... }` instead of just `public async Task FooAsync(object o) { if (o == null) throw ArgumentNullException("o"); ... }`, but I should add that I suspect my preference is an uncommon one.